# Solving Modular Arithmetic Inverses

Tags: number-theory

What is the largest three-digit integer $n$ that satisfies $$55n\equiv 165\pmod{260}~?$$

Comment: Hint: We are solving $n\equiv 3\pmod{52}$.

Comment: Oh, thnx for simplifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the values divide by 5 we can rewrite this as:

$$11n\equiv 33\pmod{52}$$

Note that $11\times3 \equiv 33 \pmod{52}$. This gives the smallest (positive) value for $n$.

Hence $3+52k \equiv 33\pmod{52}$ for integer $k$.

Increasing $k$ until $3+52k$ is just under 1000 gives $n=991$.

Comment: Very true and thnx for explaining